# Constructing a temp object and calling a method that returns a pointer - is it safe?

Tags: c++

My intution says it isn't, but the fact that everything is going on in the same line is a bit confusing. I wonder if the pointer is still valid when `cout` uses it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {
    A() : m_s("test"){ }
    const char* c_str() { return m_s.c_str(); }
    std::string m_s;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "abc " << A().c_str() << " def" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. The temporary `A()` is destroyed at the *end of the statement*. That is after cout used the pointer returned.

Answer (score 2):

The value returned by c_str() is valid as long as the std::string it was obtained from is unchanged and has not been destroyed. So your code is perfectly OK, as the temporary you create will have a lifetime equivalent to the full expression (the cout chain in this case) that it is part of.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe provided content doesn't change in between the call.

The address that is returned, is indeed pointing to valid location of the char*.